# UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 37988-37989: malformed \N character escape

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble reading a csv file into a DataFrame. Below is the code snippet.

`patron_df = pd.read_csv('Patron_Checkouts.csv', encoding = 'unicode_escape')`

I keep getting the error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 37988-37989: malformed \N character escape`

I have tried many solutions including adding an 'r'  to the right of the parentheses to get the raw string. I have also tried renaming and moving the file.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the csv file to a xlsx file and then changing:

```
patron_df = pd.read_csv('Patron_Checkouts.csv', encoding = 'unicode_escape')
```

to:

```
patron_df = pd.read_excel('Patron_Checkouts.xlsx')
```

Worked.